# Angular library export models together with library

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-library

I am trying to create an angular library which can be published to our company's private npm repository.
In my library, I want to also export classes that are used (injected via @Input()) in my library components.

Here is a model sample:

```
export class AdsToolbarMenuItem {
    iconName: string;
    label: string;
    enabled: boolean = true;
    menuAction: () => void;

    constructor(init?: Partial<AdsToolbarMenuItem>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}
```

Now what I did, was that I have exported all classes in models folder in `moduleExports.ts` like following:

```
export * from './ContactBox';
export * from './AdsToolbarMainActionItem';
export * from './AdsToolbarMenuItem';
```

Then, under `index.ts` I have included export to my component's module together with reference to these moduleExports:

```
export * from './lib/angular-components.module';
export * from './lib/models/modelExports';
```

Afterwards I succesfully package my library, publish it to NPM repository and then, in the other project I install it via npm (so far so good). I can import the main LibraryModule inside my Angular project and use exported components without any problem.

Nonetheless, as soon as I try to use any models that I exported from a library, like following:

```
import { AdsToolbarMainActionItem } from '@ads-shared/ads.shared.angular/lib/models/AdsToolbarMainActionItem';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  items: AdsToolbarMainActionItem[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.items.push(new AdsToolbarMainActionItem({ iconName: 'save' }));
  }
}
```

I get the following error message:

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts  Module not found: Error:
> Can'tresolve
> '@ads-shared/ads.shared.angular/lib/models/AdsToolbarMainActionItem'
> in 'C:\SRDEV_npx\empty-angular-project\test\src\app'

What am I doing wrong in here? Any help in respect to this matter would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these classes are exported by you library then you just need to do:

```js
import { AdsToolbarMainActionItem } from '@ads-shared/ads.shared.angular';
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Interesting is, that Visual Studio Code suggests both import paths when trying to import this class. As soon as I selected different import (as suggested) it started to work

Comment: Can you suggest, how to change my exports so that only one path would be suggested by VS Code? When I tried to export all models in the initial `index.ts` then problem was the same (VS Code suggested 2  import paths...one from main folder and the other - incorrect one, from the models folder)

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure, perhaps you can exclude the source code from being published in your library's npm package